# Объясните кусок кода из документации django

Tags: python, django

Объясните, пожалуйста, этот код, начиная с 4 строки:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
try:
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

В 4 строке, что программа пытается получить?`(pk=request.POST['choice'])`
Что значат строчки и в каком случае используются фигурные скобки - `{
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    }`
В последней строке: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))` Что значат HttpResponseRedirect, reverse и args?

Вот модели django проекта:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, в вопросе отступы, а то из-за них не рабочий и нечитаемый

Comment: Что конкретно объяснить, что в 4 строчке начинает быть непонятным? Про модели, запросы и связи всё есть в той же документации Django.

Comment: Очень много вопросов в одном посте. Глаза расплываются, не зная, на что отвечать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по порядку:

`question.choice_set` в этом месте `choice_set` - обратная связь, по всей видимости, модели `Question`, и модели `Choice`, то есть, в модели `Choice` дожна быть примерно такая строка:

`question = ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=CASCADE`

`request.POST['choice']` - попытка получить `choice` из POST переданный от клиента.

```
render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
```

Здесь в функцию `render` передаётся 3 параметра:

1. Сам запрос
2. Шаблон, который нужно отрендерить
3. Контекст - объект содержащий переменные, для отображения в шаблоне

А вот и пример из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

`render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)`

`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))` - делает редирект на путь переданный первым параметром, а вторым параметром передаются аругменты для этого шаблона